# hyperledger fabric - "go": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, gopath

I 'm new to Hyperleger Fabric and trying to done examples from [Using the Fabric test network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.5/test_network.html) documentation. I'm stuck on the phase of starting a chaincode on the channel. I am getting error located below even though I have adjusted paths properly. I couldn't figure out the solution from similar questions.

The command:

> sudo ./network.sh deployCC -c channeluk1 -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go

Here is the output:

```
> Using docker and docker-compose
deploying chaincode on channel 'channeluk1'
executing with the following
> - CHANNEL_NAME: channeluk1
> - CC_NAME: basic
> - CC_SRC_PATH: ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go
> - CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: go
> - CC_VERSION: 1.0
> - CC_SEQUENCE: 1
> - CC_END_POLICY: NA
> - CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
> - CC_INIT_FCN: NA
> - DELAY: 3
> - MAX_RETRY: 5
> - VERBOSE: false
> Vendoring Go dependencies at ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go
~/go/src/github.com/umitkilic/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go ~/go/src/github.com/umitkilic/fabric-samples/test-network
scripts/deployCC.sh: line 59: go: command not found
~/go/src/github.com/umitkilic/fabric-samples/test-network
> Finished vendoring Go dependencies
> + peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go --lang golang --label basic_1.0
> + res=1
> ++ peer lifecycle chaincode calculatepackageid basic.tar.gz
Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz': open basic.tar.gz: no such file or directory
> + PACKAGE_ID=
> Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: failed to determine module root: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH
Chaincode packaging has failed
Deploying chaincode failed
```

I know the error says there is something wrong about GO path but no problem about path. Here is some outputs for go.

Command:

> go env

Output:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/umitkilic/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/umitkilic/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/umitkilic/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/home/umitkilic/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/home/umitkilic/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/umitkilic/go/src/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build952499924=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Command:

> whereis go

Output:

> go: /home/umitkilic/go/bin/go

(In go env output, GOPATH="/home/umitkilic/go" but in whereis go output it says go: /home/umitkilic/go/bin/go. I'm not sure if these are in coherent.)

In my ~/.bashrc file I have following lines:

> export GOPATH=$HOME/go
> export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

My fabric samples directory is Home/umitkilic/go/src/github.com/umitkilic/fabric-samples

My go version go1.13.15 linux/amd64.

I tried to install go language in /usr/local/go but the result is the same error.

Can you help me please?

**Update:**
I used newest version before such as go1.20.4 from [official website](https://go.dev/doc/install) following their instruction. The result was the same error.

By the way, I used below command to print fabric peer version:

```
 docker exec -it cli bash
 root@bb4a6d6eed2f:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer version
```

The output is:

```
peer:
 Version: v2.5.0
 Commit SHA: bd8e248
 Go version: go1.20.2
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
```

It says Go version is go1.20.2 but I have never download and install this version of Go. Maybe this automatically installed with fabric samples in Docker. I am not sure wheather it is relevant to the error.

Comment: Can you try go to the error: `scripts/deployCC.sh: line 59: go: command not found`
`scripts/deployCC.sh` line `59` and before the command to run Go, insert your debugging info eg. `which go` `whereis go` `env` `etc` and see why it is not finding it and what has changed at this point?

Comment: Your version of Go is helplessly outdated.

Comment: @Volker I used go1.20.4 also. It produces the same error. Not about version I think.

Comment: @jamylak I added which go and whereis go before the related line. The result is strangely returns empty.
The result is just one line >
go:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sudo ./network.sh ...

The issue is that you run the script as the `root` user (with `sudo`). And the `root` user has its own environment variables. You can verify that the `go` command is not in the `root`'s `$PATH` like this:

```
$ sudo sh
# echo $PATH
```

There could be too many environmental differences between `root` and the current login user. For example, the `root` user has different `$GOENV` that could affect the `go` command. So my suggestion is: do not bother to modify the `root`'s `$PATH`; instead, [run the Docker daemon as a non-root user](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) (also see this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo).

And then execute the script without `sudo`:

```
./network.sh deployCC -c channeluk1 -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
```

Comment: This was the problem. This solved my problem, big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your go env and whereis go outputs, it seems that Go is installed in `/home/umitkilic/go/` and the go binary is located in `/home/umitkilic/go/bin/go`. "go: command not found" error is evidence that go binary is not in your system's PATH. Add it to path as:

```bash
# In your .bashrc file
export PATH=$PATH:/home/umitkilic/go/bin
```

Now, reload your ~/.bashrc file with `source ~/.bashrc`. After this, you should be able to check the version of Go by `go version`.

Then, retry your deployment again.

Comment: I already have "export GOPATH=$HOME/go export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin" in my bashrc file as stated in question. Nevertheless, your suggestion is added to .bashrc. The results is the same. whereis go still produce /home/umitkilic/go/bin/go and error stays.

Answer (score 0):

Install with `sudo apt-get install golang` then deploy the chain code.